# Using mutate to output value from named vector

Tags: r, dplyr

I have 1X2 dataframe with values 'sent1' and 'sent2'.

```
test.df <- data.frame(sentence = c('sent1', 'sent2'))
```

I also have a reference vector that has values for the combination of the 2 sentences and 3 categories (a, b, c).

```
test.vec <- c(sent1_a = 1, 
         sent1_b = 0, 
         sent1_c = 1,
         sent2_a = 0,
         sent2_b = 1,
         sent2_c = 1)
```

I would like to create a new df that looks like this:

```
output.df <- data.frame(sentence = c('sent1', 'sent2'),
                    a = c(1,0),
                    b = c(0,1),
                    c = c(0,1))

output.df
#  sentence a b c
#1    sent1 1 0 0
#2    sent2 0 1 1
```

Ideally, I would like to use mutate to select the relevant values from the vector based on the corresponding sentence that I'm looping through

```
results <- test.df %>%
           mutate(a = test.vec[[paste0(sentence, '_a')]])
```

However, I'm getting an error on this.

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
>     Evaluation error: attempt to select more than one element in vectorIndex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reshape `test.vec` to the output you need:

```
library(tidyverse)
data.frame(test.vec) %>% 
    tibble::rownames_to_column() %>% 
    separate(rowname, c('sentence', 'vars')) %>% 
    spread(vars, test.vec)

#  sentence a b c
#1    sent1 1 0 1
#2    sent2 0 1 1
```